# How catch this exception

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

Hello I have a problem with this code

```
try {
        double pom = imageHEX[0][0].real();
        if (imageHEX != nullptr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIRKA; ++i) {
                delete[] imageHEX[i];
            }
            delete[] imageHEX;
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        throw Vynimka(3);
    }
```

program crashed when try delete deleted array.

But I don't k `double pom = imageHEX[0][0].real();` and try catch exception with try read from unexist index but I don't know how is called those exception.

Destructor work good while program work, but when Application exit making problems. I don't know why.

Have you som ideas how solve this problem? thanks

/// my question is how catch all exception in catch block. or how catch exception when try read from index which not exist.

something like in Java class Exception. - > catch ALL exception in java.

```
this try {
} catch (...){
 ... something 
}
```

not work, program crashed too..

this error

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000013F877BF2 in Semestrelka2D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: i update question

Comment: Use `at` instead of `[]` to have exception for out of bound accesses.

Comment: use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of allocating your own arrays, that makes this entire issue irrelevant

Comment: A crash is not an exception.  This is not Java.

Comment: andwhat is crash?

Comment: @trip06 One possible result of Undefined Behaviour. `catch (...)` will indeed catch all C++ exceptions, but accessing invalid memory does not cause a C++ exception. On Windows (which you seem to be using), it may I believe raise a Structured Exception (a  Windows thing). Google for "structured exception handling" if that's what you're after.

Comment: and how it use? -- for me

Comment: Note: Microsoft's runtime unhelpfully calls access violations "exceptions", but these are SEH exceptions (the MS equivalent of UNIX signals), not C++ exceptions. They have nothing to do with `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 2):

> program crashed when try delete deleted array.

Standard describes this situation as "undefined behavior". The program may or may not crash, but even if it does not crash, it is still an invalid program.

There is no exception thrown on undefined behavior, so there is nothing to catch. The only thing you can do is to avoid deleting items that have already been deleted, and also avoid accessing deleted items.

Running your program through a memory profiler, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), will help you identify all sorts of memory issues that cause undefined behavior - reading or writing past the allocated region, accessing and deleting items that have been deleted, and so on.

In your situation it appears that switching to `std::vector` would help you manage resources automatically.

Comment: i can' use vector,  because everything work good while program runnung (when debbug line by line in descturtor steps for 2X) but crashed only when I close program. 

I need get if need array destruct or not. I dot't know why

Comment: @trip06 It's undefined behavior somewhere in your program. "Working good" is only an illusion: if the program crashes before exiting, it has caused undefined behavior at some earlier point. These bugs are notoriously hard to find. Frustration in the industry caused by these bugs are at least partially responsible for invention and proliferation of Java, C#, etc. You can try to catch them with valgrind, or avoid them by switching to vector. You can also do both, because vectors do not protect your program from every kind of undefined behavior.

Comment: when i comment /* */ destructor program work good.

Comment: @trip06 The cause of the crash is *not* the destructor. By the time the destructor runs, the damage has been done. Program not crashing does not mean that it works good. Memory profiler is your friend.

Comment: and where is a problem?

Comment: @trip06 Run memory profiler, it's going to tell you where it is. Follow the link to valgrind, follow its quick start guide, run your code, and see where the problems are.